# problem installing dotnet cli on Ubuntu - can't remove old version of dotnet core

Tags: dotnet

I'm having a difficult time installing the latest DotNet Core CLI tools on Ubuntu 16.04.  I believe it's because I have a much older version installed and I (this is embarrassing)... I don't know how to remove it.

When I enter `dotnet --version` into a terminal window, 
I get... `1.0.0-preview1-002702`

That prevents me from using the very nice DotNet Core installation instructions here: https://www.microsoft.com/net/learn/get-started/linuxubuntu

I can follow those instructions, but at the end, I'm still left with the results from `dotnet --version` equal to `1.0.0-preview1-002702`.

I'm guessing I need to use `apt remove` but I don't know what name to use to remove it.

Answer (score 1):

As is typical, I discover the solution not long after posting a request for help!

I found the solution here: https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/4088

To remove an older version of .NET Core, simply remove the folder you had added named "dotnet" on disk.  But then you must **restart** your computer.

From there, you can use the instructions listed here to install the latest .NET Core https://www.microsoft.com/net/learn/get-started/linuxubuntu